# Xcode 8.2 can't change simulator device in down panel

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am completely new to iOS programming and one of the things I am having difficulty is in changing the simulator device in main storyboard bottom panel (image below).

Although I can change the device in top left but I don't see the device ( 6s e.g in this case) in the bottom panel. I can change the orientation but don't see all the device. Please let me know what I am missing.

Please note that I don't see all devices when I click on **View as: iPhone7(wChR)** . The reason I want to switch to iphone6 in storyboard view is because default iphone& covers up my whole screen.

[image: following panel]

[image]

Comment: Its just the device size, iPhone 6S and iPhone 6 are same iPhone 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaurav,

You have completely misunderstood Xcode, the left top drop down you changed and selected 6s shows what device will be used to load your app. So when you hit run you will see iPhone 6S popping out and loading your app. This got nothing to do with device panel in main.storyboard :)

The devices that you see in device panel of main.storyboard represents the devices of various size classes. If in case you aren't aware of what size classes are, I suggest you should have look into size class concepts, before diving deep into app development :)

Anyway you can change the device size class in main.storyboard by clicking on the device images listed below.As you can see one of the iPhone is selected which of size class (c X w) if you click on iPad you will see that device frame in storyboard will change and show size class as (R x R)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks Sandeep...I got most you suggested, my initial dilemma was that I don't see all devices when I click in device panel. Updating the main question with adding respective image. Thanks for suggestion for Size Classes.

Comment: @gaurav : You won't get all the devices buddy :) Thats what I was trying to explain you in above answer :) It is not the devices list in your xCode :) They are the representatives of various size classes and few handpicked devices from Xcode which covers almost all possible sizes :) just to see allow you to customise UI for all possible size classes and and all possible sizes :)